# Prove $f$ has a pole at $\pi n$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a non constant meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that all poles of $f$ are of the form $n\pi$ for some integer $n$, assume that for all non-real $z$ we have the estimate $$|f(z)|\leq (1+|\text{Im}(z)|^{-1})|e^{-|\text{Im}(z)|},$$ prove that for every integer $n$, $f$ has a pole at $\pi n$.

It is clear by the estimation that for every integer $n$, $f$ is either holomorphic or a simple pole at $\pi n$. Furthermore, by multiplying $f(z)$ by $\sin (z)$, we have $$|f(z)\sin(z)|\leq 1+\frac{1}{|\text{Im}(z)|}.$$ Here $f(z)\sin(z)$ is entire.

Alternatively, we have $$|f(z)e^{-iz}|\leq 1+\frac{1}{|\text{Im}(z)|}$$ as well.

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Can someone give me a hint as to how to finish the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Note that if $g$ is an entire function st $|g(z)|\leq 1+\frac{1}{|\text{Im}(z)|}$, $g$ is bounded outside of any horizontal strip that includes the real axis; hence if $g$ doesn't grow very, very fast (faster than any $e^{e^{C|z|}}$), Lindelof applies and $g$ is bounded hence constant; so it is enough to show that $g$ cannot grow too fast and that is easy

Comment: @Conrad I spent several hours trying to show that $g$ doesn't grow too fast, but I have trouble seeing why this is true. The difficulty is that the problem doesn't give us any control over how $g$ grows horizontally.

Comment: $z=Re^{i\theta}, |g(z)|\leq 1+\frac{1}{R|\sin \theta|}$ so $\log |g| \le -c\log |\theta|$ for $\theta$ small compared to $R$ but $\log |\theta|$ is integrable near $0$ so one can get upper bounds for $\log |g(w)|$ by subharmonicity and integration on large circles centered at $w$ (here we can assume $w$ close to the real axis as otherwise bounds are trivial...) - if need more details I can put an answer

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! I think I know why $g$ is bounded now.

Comment: happy to help more if needed